# ¿Por qué una consulta desde PHP a MySQL devuelve 0 en vez del valor de la fila?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```php
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    include("template/head.php");
    include("template/mainheader.php");
    include ("db_files/db.php");
    $state = array(
        1 => $lang['state_name_string_1'],
        2 => $lang['state_name_string_2'],
        3 => $lang['state_name_string_3'],
        4 => $lang['state_name_string_4'],
    );
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        $sql="SELECT estado FROM tickets WHERE telefono = '".$_POST['consultphone']."' OR imei = '".$_POST['consultimei']."'";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if ($result=mysqli_query($db,$sql)){
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                ?>
                <div class="content container" style="margin-bottom:100px">
                    <center><h3>Datos de su pedido</h3></center>
                    <div class="row main-content">
                        <label>Estado del pedido</label>
                        <?php 
                        echo $result['estado']; 
                        //echo $state[$result['estado']]; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php


                }
            } else {
                    echo "no hay registros para su busqueda";
            }
        mysqli_close($db);
    }
    include("template/footer.php");
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y el resultado que me imprime es `0`, cuando en la tabla hay 2 registros y los dos deberían ser `1`

Aquí el resultado directamente desde phpmyadmin:

[image: resultado de consulta con 2 registros valor 1]

Y esto es lo que me sale en mi web:

[image: texto con ressultado: 0]

Añado el formulario:

```html
<form action="consult.php" method="post">
    <label class="dropdown-label"><?php echo $lang['header_consult_string_4']; ?></label>
    <label class="dropdown-label"><?php echo $lang['header_consult_string_1']; ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="consultphone"/>
    <label class="dropdown-label"><?php echo $lang['header_consult_string_2']; ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="consultimei"/>
    <button class="my-btn btn-primary my-btn-primary">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Añado el código que me funcionaba a medias antes con este me daba el resultado correcto pero solo una vez:

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
 <body>
 <?php
 include("template/head.php");
 include("template/mainheader.php");
 include ("db_files/db.php");
 $state = array(
  1 => $lang['state_name_string_1'],
  2 => $lang['state_name_string_2'],
  3 => $lang['state_name_string_3'],
  4 => $lang['state_name_string_4'],
 );
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 if (isset($_POST['consultphone']) || isset($_POST['consultimei'])){
  $sql="SELECT * FROM pre_tickets WHERE telefono = '".$_POST['consultphone']."'";
  $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  if ($result=mysqli_query($db,$sql))
   {
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($rowcount >0){
     while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      if($_POST['consultphone'] == $result['telefono']  || $_POST['consultimei'] == $result['imei']){
      ?>
      <div class="content container" style="margin-bottom:100px">
       <center><h3>Datos de su pedido</h3></center>
       <div class="row main-content">
        <label>Estado del pedido</label>
        <?php echo $state[$result['estado']]; ?>
       </div>
      </div>
      <?php
      } elseif ($_POST['consultphone'] != $result['telefono'] && $_POST['consultimei'] != $result['imei']){
       echo "datos incorrectos";
       
      }
     }
    }
   }

  mysqli_close($db);
 }
 $db->close();
 include("template/footer.php");
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el formulario desde donde recupera el $_POST?

Comment: Acabo de subirlo

Comment: En tu formulario te falta ponerle al botón type="submit"

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar correctamente.

Comment: ¿Te aparece algún error? ¿O simplemente no aparece el valor?

Comment: Sale como la imagen. Donde  debería poner estado del pedido: 1 (esto debería aparecer dos veces, ya que hay dos registros como se puede ver en la imagen del phpmyadmin) sale estado del pedido: 0, no sé de donde saca ese valor ya que no hay ningún registro con ese valor. Además tampoco me devuelve la cantidad, ya que en vez de dos registros me devuelve solo 1.

Comment: Eliminá completamente el IF de `if ($result=mysqli_query($db,$sql)){` (obviamente también el `} else {`) y probá de nuevo

Comment: Eliminando tanto el if como el else que viene detrás sigue saliendo el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando hagas el mysqli_fetch_array pásale el segundo parámetro  MYSQLI_ASSOC así podrás acceder de forma asociativa a tu array de valores.

Además creo que tienes un error, hay que pasarle $result, no $query.

Sería así:

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```

Fuente: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, lee los comentarios que te he colocado. La consulta se estaba ejecutando dos veces. Tambien te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/18233#18233)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    include("template/head.php");
    include("template/mainheader.php");
    include ("db_files/db.php");
    $state = array(
        1 => $lang['state_name_string_1'],
        2 => $lang['state_name_string_2'],
        3 => $lang['state_name_string_3'],
        4 => $lang['state_name_string_4'],
    );
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    }else{

      //Se comprueba que se hayan recibido los datos, si no se han recibido, no se continuará la ejecución
      if(isset($_POST['consultphone']) && isset($_POST['consultimei'])){

         //Evitamos inyecciones SQL
         $consultphone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['consultphone']);
         $consultimei = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['consultimei']);

         //Consulta SQL con las variables anteriores
      $sql="SELECT estado FROM tickets WHERE telefono = '$consultphone' OR imei = '$consultimei'";

       //Ejecutamos la consulta 1 sola vez, antes se hacia 2 veces.
      $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

       // Si hay resultados se muestran, sino se imprime mensaje de que no hay registros.
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)!=0){
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                ?>
                <div class="content container" style="margin-bottom:100px">
                    <center><h3>Datos de su pedido</h3></center>
                    <div class="row main-content">
                        <label>Estado del pedido</label>
                        <?php 
                        echo $result['estado'];
                        ?> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php

                }

            } else {
                    echo "no hay registros para su busqueda";
            }
        mysqli_close($db);


      }

    }
    include("template/footer.php");
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me sale el mismo resultado...

Comment: ¿Te sale el mensaje "no hay registros para su busqueda"?

Comment: No, simplemente me sale el resultado 0 y ya está...

Comment: Acabo de añadir el código que funcionaba medianamente bien, con ese código salia bien el resultado pero solo salía 1 en vez de los dos que hay.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba `print_r($result);die();` a ver si te da alguna pista.

prueba2:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM pre_tickets WHERE telefono = '".$_POST['consultphone']."'";
print_r($sql);die();
```

Y mira a ver como se esta formando la query.

Comment: esto es lo que sale : Array ( [0] => 0 [estado] => 0 )

Comment: @PavloB. Haz un echo de la consulta y mira a ver si de verdad tiene que devolver datos esa consulta directamente en la base de datos.

Comment: a me da que no estas mandando bien los parametros desde la pagina prueba a $sql="SELECT * FROM pre_tickets WHERE telefono = '".$_POST['consultphone']."'";

Comment: print_r($sql);die(); debajo de la linea anterior y mira a ver si se esta formando bien la consulta.